# Flask Dance generating incorrect callback URL

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, flask-dance

I had some issues implementing Flask Dance for Google OAuth.
the callback URL is working fine on localhost, but when I deploy the app on my server, it generates an incorrect callback URL.

For example, I have configured the callback URL in the Google console to be https://subdomain-app.domain.co/google_login/google/authorized
But, when I open up the Google login page it says the callback URL is incorrect which is https://domain/google_login/google/authorized

How to fix that?